# How to test response of a Python script on one line?

Tags: shell-script

Following an example I have been provided, I'm reading a result from another script to determine course of action.

`isOK=$(somepythonscript.py --someParametersHere)`

`if [ "$isOK" = true ]; then`

When I echo value of isOK (`echo "isOK=$isOK"`), I see `isOK=true` and `isOK=false`, depending on arguments I pass.

Would it be possible to collapse this into one statement to this effect?

`if [ $(somepythonscript.py) = true]; then`

I have been reading about shell scripting and my understanding is that `= true` isn't a test of a boolean value and more of a misunderstood effect that people assume is working like a boolean. If this is safe, I can bet on this, as well. But if there is a better way to test response of this other Python script, I am open to it. Please note, that I cannot change the other Python script.

Comment: Does `somepythonscript.py` actually print out the string `true` or are you thinking of Python' `True`? I mean, are you talking about matching a specific string or do you want to look at the script's exit status and if it succeeded? Are you just looking for `if somepythonscript.py; then "echo worked"; else echo "failed"; fi`?

Comment: I don't have the source code for the Python script. I test it with different arguments and echo what is assigned to isOK. Sometimes I get `isOK=true`, sometimes `isOK=false`. So I'm wondering if I can remove this isOK variable and still test the result. What I have shown is a working example but I'm hoping to remove the isOK, as it appears redundant.

Comment: And what happens when you try it? I mean, yes, `var=$(command); [ $var = whatever ];` is exactly equivalent to `[ $(command) = whatever ]`, but since simply trying it would demonstrate that, I am guessing you are asking for something more.

Comment: I have made this change and want to test it but still don't have my pull request approved. So in the meantime, I wanted to ask experienced admins if this is looking good or if I'm wasting time waiting for deployment. I think you're telling me there's a good chance this will work.

Comment: You'll have to be careful since `true` is a Unix command so depending on the context in which you use `true` in your code it'll be that command or it'll be a literal string. Ditto for `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The construct `$(command)` is a way of treating the output of `command` as a variable, so it is essentially equivalent to `var=$(command)` and then using `$var`. So if you don't need to keep the output, you don't need a variable and this is enough:

```
if [ "$(command)" = "true" ]; then
  # do your thing
fi
```

Just remember that `true` and `false` are just strings as far as the shell (`bash`, in your case) is concerned. They don't have any special meaning, unlike `True` and `False` in Python.

Finally, the more common idiom for this sort of thing is to use a command's exit status which is `0` on success and non-0 on failure. So, if your Python script is written well and exits with a non-0 status on failure, it might even be enough to simply do:

```
if somepythonscript.py --someParametersHere
then
  echo "The script worked!"
else
  echo "the script failed!"
fi
```

Comment: Regarding true and false not having any special meaning - there are Unix commands with those names so they do have a special meaning and the OP will have to be careful of the context in which they use them to avoid potentially cryptic errors.

Comment: @EdMorton well yes, but that isn't really relevant here. That's like saying that the string `cd` has a special meaning in the shell because it is also the name of a builtin. The point is that the shell uses `0` and `1` in the way that Python uses `True` and `False`, so the strings `true` and `false` have no special meaning. Yes, there are the builtin `true` and `false` commands in bash, and other shells, as well as the binaries `/sbin/true` and `/sbin/false` but those are completely different things.

Comment: It's relevant if/when the OP decides to use `true` or `false` in some other context not knowing it's a command and gets a cryptic result. If they didn't have a special meaning then you could just type `"true"` or `true` at the command prompt or in any other context and get a similar result to just typing `"foo"` or `foo` but that's not the case.